# How to append angular data into php function?

Tags: php, angularjs

I wonder if it is possible to append angular data into a php function. For example:

```
<li ng-repeat='item in items'><?php echo formatPeriode("{{ item.period }}") ?></li>
```

And here is the function in php

```
function formatPeriode($period){
   $year = substr($period, 0, 4);
   $month = substr($period, 4, 2);

   return $month . ' ' . $year;
}
```

I know it looks awkward and it's not working anyway. But somehow I need a solution for it.

Comment: Angular is javascript, javascript is interpreted at client-side, not server-side (where PHP lives), that why it doesn't work.

Comment: yes I agree with you. I just wonder how to append angular data into php function (if possible). I actually can make it using angular filter or maybe as pointed out by @Benjamin using momentjs

Answer (score 3):

As @catcon said, no you can't because the PHP code is evaluated first at the server-side, then at the client-side the javascript. 
A simple format function can be written in angular pretty easily, for working with dates, check out the [moment](https://momentjs.com/) libary, it has a long list of tools for such.